Source for Secret Signs that Yaakov gave Rachel
I heard some time ago that Kaf haChaim or some other author suggests that the secret signs that Yaakov gave Rachel were the places of the body, where later the kohanim had oil and blood applied during their inauguration: right ear, right thumb, and right big toe. Is it possible to identify the source for this midrash and explain the connection?

Hi Y DJ! Try to ask your questions one-by-one, because otherwise they will be closed and won't get answered.

סד) קודם תשמיש תאחז האשה בוהן רגל ימין של בעלה ואח"כ בוהן ידו הימנית ואח"כ תנוך אזנו הימנית ובשעה שמחזקת תכוין שיסתלקו מעליו הג' שדים המעוררים התאוה שלא לשם שמים. וזהו הסימנים שמסר יעקב לרחל חס"ל נהר ס"א. פת"ע או מ"א:
https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.240.64.2

@אילפא Yishar Kochacha! Could you write as an answer? +10

Thanks to אילפא for linking to the correct section of Kaf HaChaim on Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 240:64:1-2 from Sefaria.
The Kaf HaChaim indicates precisely where he took it from. The tradition is passed down by Rabbi Avraham Azulai in Sefer Chesed l'Avraham, Even Shetiyah, Maayan 2, Nahar 61:1-2.
The full explanation is about proper marital relations between husband and wife and how it should always be at the initiation of the wife and not be initiated at the discretion of the husband nor because of the desire of the husband.
Interestingly enough, it also connects this to the proper practice of Kapparot by a man on erev Yom Kippur when using a rooster. The full text is:

נהר סא - בסוד תנוך אוזן ובהן יד ורגל, ובסוד סימנים שמסר יעקב לרחל:
דע כי יש ג' שרים גדולים מסטרא דשמאלא והם המתעוררים את האדם לרדוף אחר
תאות גופניות, אחד משכנו על תנוך אוזן הימנית והוא הגדול, והבינוני על
בוהן יד הימנית, והקטן על בוהן רגל הימנית, ועל ידי נתינת הכהן מדם האשם
על ג' מקומות האלו מסתלקים מעליו השרים הנזכרים, כמו שעל ידי הזאת מי
חטאת על טמא מת מסתלק מעליו טומאת המת שהוא רוח טומאה מסטרא דשמאלא, וכך
צריך ליתן מדם התרנגול הנשחט לכפרה בערבי יום הכפורים על תנוך האוזן
המכפר הימנית ועל בהן ידו הימנית ועל בהן רגלו הימנית, ובזה מסתלקים
מעליו השרים המעוררים אותו לרדוף אחר תאות גופניות, והם הם המעוררים הם
ההמקטרגים, ובהסתלקם מעליו ניצול מתובע וממקטרג, ואין שום ב"ד יכול לידון
מבלי תובע. וכן הענין בסוד התשמיש כשהתעוררות בא מהזכר אותו התשמיש אינו
לשם שמים כי אם לשם תענוג, ואע"פ שאי אפשר להיות התחלת התשמיש שלא יהיה
לשם תענוג מצד זה נולדה הערלה כנזכר לעיל, אבל הזוכה לאשה כשרה שכל תשמיש
ותשמיש בא על ידי התעורותה, ועל ידי שאוחזת בידה בתנוך אזן בעלה הימני
ובוהן ידו הימני ובוהן רגלו הימני בזמן שכוונתה לעורר אותו, צריכה
שתתכוון לבה בשעה שמחזקת באלו הג' סימנים שיסתלקו מעליו הג' שרים
המעוררים התאוה שלא לשם שמים, וכאשר יתכוון הוא לקיים מצות עונה לבד ולא
לשום תענוג כלל, אז אפשר לאותו עובר לצאת מהול ממעי אמו, ואלו הסימנים
שמסר יעקב לרחל, ואמנם האשה צריכה להתחיל מהבהן הרגל שהוא הסימן התחתון,
ואח"כ מבהן היד שהוא האמצעי, ואח"כ בתנוך אזן בעלה שהוא העליון, ובדרך זה
מסרן יעקב לרחל, מסכ"י, וזמש"ל:

That in context, this is a tradition which follows after the two covenants established by G-d with Avraham, namely the upper covenant over proper thoughts and speech. The brain being between the two ears, and the mouth, which is in between the two hands.
And the lower covenant of circumcision which is between the two feet.

Thank you. This answer also suitable for my other question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/144143/midrash-about-yetzer-hara. Originally I put them together but was adviced to split them.
