Midrash about yetzer hara
I heard a midrash which describes yetzer hara, the evil inclination, as acting through his 3 generals: one pulls the person's right ear, one pulls the person's right thumb, and one pulls the person's right toe. Is it possible to find a source and explain the midrash connection to the procedure of inauguration of cohanim and purification of metzorah. In the first instance the Torah describes blood and oil being applied to kohen's right ear, right thumb, and right big toe. In the second, only blood is applied.

This idea is cited in Chesed L’Avraham (Even Sh’siya, Ein Hakorei, Nahar 61) by the kabbalist Abraham ben Mordecai Azulai:

דע כי יש ג' שרים גדולים מסטרא דשמאלא והם המתעוררים את האדם לרדוף אחר תאות גופניות, אחד משכנו על תנוך אוזן הימנית והוא הגדול, והבינוני על בוהן יד הימנית, והקטן על בוהן רגל הימנית, ועל ידי נתינת הכהן מדם האשם על ג' מקומות האלו מסתלקים מעליו השרים הנזכרים, כמו שעל ידי הזאת מי חטאת על טמא מת מסתלק מעליו טומאת המת שהוא רוח טומאה מסטרא דשמאלא

He goes on to explain it at some length. There may be an earlier (perhaps Midrashic) source, but this should be a start.
